# How can I use Backbone.Model.save() if my whole app and data is local?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm making a totally local Backbone app, no server-side included, and I provide the app with some initial local data. The data is actually the Collection data which is a json file and stored in a folder called data. So I provide the Collection with a url attribute which is `data/datalist.json` and use `this.collection.fetch()` to get the inital data. All works well.

But I want any update happens in View would save changes to the corresponding Model data in this Collection json data file. It seems that `this.model.save({name: newName})` doesn't work for me. Every time I refresh the whole page, the app will still show the inital data file. So how should I change the data file when a item in View is updated, deleted or created? Do I need to set a url attribute in Model?

Answer (score 2):

Model.save calls the Backbone.sync method, which by default maps CRUD functions to a REST api. If you want to use something other than REST for save/update/delete, then you need to override Backbone.sync.

There is a local storage plugin that overrides sync on Github, which is endorsed by Backbonejs: [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage)

This plugin should persist your data while the app is running.  You may need to extend it if you want to write changes to your filesystem (not sure, haven't used it myself).  Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: The only downside to localStorage and sessionStorage is the older browsers that do not support them, so you might consider something like Lawnchair (http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/adapters/) which provides some wrapper for older technologies to give you a wider base of functioning browsers. What eterps said still holds though, you just might need to create a new Backbone.sync which uses Lawnchair instead.

Comment: @JohnMunsch If I use modern browsers such as chrome or firefox, Is localStorage plugin alone eterps mentioned not enough? I **have to** create a new Backbone.sync?

Comment: @chaonextdoor Absolutely not. If you consult a good tool like "When can I use..." (http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) and it says that all the browsers you intend to support have localStorage available, just use it. Even if not, if most of the browsers do support it, come back later and swap out for a different version of sync later and add more browsers support once you have a good working app and people who want to use it.

Comment: @JohnMunsch Sorry, I'm a little bit confused. So by absolutely not, you mean localstorage alone is absolutely not enough or absolutely not have to create a new Backbone.sync if I use localstorage in modern browsers?

Comment: @chaonextdoor My apologies. I should have made that clearer. My comment was in answer to your question, "I have to create a new Backbone.sync?" No. Just do what eterps said and use the local storage plugin. You will only need to create a new custom one if you ever decide localStorage doesn't cover all the browsers you want to support.